# Internet Explorer 9 (and 10) are rendering my rounded corners backwards

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css, right-to-left

Basically what it does is render the top-right and bottom-right corners round instead of the correct top+bottom-left corners.

Here's the css:

```
.formlabel, .formlabel2, .formhead{
    width:200px;
    font-size:18px;
    height:22px;
    font-weight:normal;
    background-color:#FF8000;
    text-align:right;
    margin-top:5px;
    padding-right:1px;
    border:none;
    color:white;    
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

From what I've been able to deduce, it happens because they're within another class that has the `direction:rtl` attribute. If I add `direction:ltr` to the above classes, then the corners are rounded correctly. (You can try this by using the above code and adding `direction:rtl`)

The problem is that the site is in Hebrew so I need it to stay rtl.

Any ideas?

Comment: Stupid _stupid_ IE developers. Just a little conformity would be nice now and then.

Comment: Perhaps you could use absolute positioning to stack two elements and put the background and border and direction: ltr to the lower element and all the rtl content on the upper element?

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought a simple solution would be to place a conditional comment in the `<head>` for IE9+ to use css which you have reversed.

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
    <style>
        .formlabel, .formlabel2, .formhead{
            border-top-right-radius: 5px; /* switched from left */
            border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; /* switched from left */
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

If you prefer, instead of using `style` in the conditional comment, you could link to a separate external stylesheet instead.

Comment: Conditional comments are no more supported in IE10.

Comment: @duri: That is interesting. Though it will still work for IE9, and hopefully by the time IE10 is finalised it will be corrected, assuming someone informs them of the issue.

Comment: @jontsef: As I originally thought, having tested in IE10 the bug has been fixed, so the conditional statement above will work for IE9. Therefore problem solved :)